# WSO2 OAuth Validation Error between Identity Server and Integration Studio

Tags: wso2

We are attempting to use the OAuth Mediator in Integration Studio to validate a token with the WSO2 Identity Server.

The token we are using is valid on the Identity Server because testing through SOAP UI returns a valid response. However, we are unable to do so using the OAuth Mediator in Integration Studio. We are using a password grant type.

**When we attempt to pass the call through the OAuth mediator we receive the below errors:**

```
WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - ERROR_EXCEPTION : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error **occured while validating** oauth 2.0 access token

WARN {API_LOGGER.UserInfoRestAPI} - ERROR_CODE : 0 *ERROR_MESSAGE : Error occured while validating oauth 2.0 access token*

WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - FaultHandler : org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler@1f7c8500

WARN {org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler} - Executing fault handler mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator

WARN {API_LOGGER.UserInfoRestAPI} - Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
```

For reference, we are using [this documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/OAuth+Token+Validation+Using+SOAP+Service).

Calling the web service through SOAP UI returns successfully as shown here:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Information about the setup:

- WSO2 Integration Studio: 7.0.2
- WSO2 Identity Server: 5.10.0 (Running on port 9446)
- All services are running on the same virtual machine

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 EI 7.0.2 and even 6.6 are using org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub_6.1.0 containing oauth stub classes that are not compatible with WSO2 Identity Server 5.10. So what you need to do is:

- Copy org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub_6.4.2,jar from WSO2 Identity Server to the wso2\components\plugins folder of the WSO2 EI 6.6 or 7.X
- Update wso2\components\default\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info replacing the old entry with the new updated one. 
  org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub,6.4.2,../plugins/org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub_6.4.2.jar,4,true
  Restart.

The error should go away. However, this is not a very clean solution and maybe WSO2 should release a fix updating the WSO2 OAuth Mediator java classes.

Comment: Thank you Marwan. That is a great workaround. I will check with the WSO2 support team for any incompatibilities.